# My mirror ball is not shading correctly - it looks too flat

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, mirror

I have a 32x32 UV sphere in blender. I have it set to "shade flat".

What I want is each square face to be clearly defined and visible (like shading flat normally does).

It looks basically correct in Look Dev mode:

[image]

However, even though it looks correct in Look Dev mode, when I render it looks like this:
[image]

I am pointing a square area light right at the object and that is all I see.

The white part of the material is glossy so ideally it would create a mirror look (where each face would reflect its background).

The holes are created by an alpha map, ideally the white parts around them would be glossy.

How can I get the "look dev" look, in my render?

Comment: Can you show your material setup?

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The look dev mode uses an HDRI which is why you see a reflection. There is nothing to reflect besides the area light in your scene when you do the final render.

Comment: @rjg this should be the answer.  Please submit it as one.

Answer (score 2):

The *Look Dev* mode uses an HDRI which produces the nice reflections in your first image. As the name suggests the *Look Dev* mode is only meant to develop the look of your model, not for a preview of the final render, that is what the *Rendered* mode is for. If you want to use the scene's world settings instead of the HDRI preset in *Look Dev*, you can enable *Scene World* in the *Viewport Shading* settings.

[image: Viewport Shading Settings]

In order to use an HDRI in your render, you'll have to set it up in the world tab or its node editor.

---

### Blender 2.80

[image]
[image]

---

### Blender 2.81

[image]
[image]